# Zero vector in a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I know that every vector space contains a zero element so that u + 0 = 0 + u = u but I am not sure if every vector space contains the literal vector with all zero elements or if it is just a vector that *acts* as a zero vector?

I'm especially wondering this question because a fact about subspaces is that every vector space has at least two subspaces: itself and the zero vector {0}. But in this case, I am not sure if this refers to the vector with all zero elements or if it refers to the vector in the vector space that just *acts* like a zero vector

Comment: 'Vector of zeros' has no meaning in general.

Comment: Although you need to be able to multiply by scalars in a vector space, the elements of a vector space don't need to be represented using numbers or tuples at all. You could make the set $$\rm \{apple,\,orange,\,banana,\,kiwi\}$$ a vector space if you wanted to. Typically though you do call the zero vector by the symbol $0$, since it makes everything easier.

Comment: “...has at least two subspaces...” : if you mean two *distinct* subspaces, then no — $\{0\}$ itself only has one.

Answer (score 2):

A vector space $V$ over the real numbers is a set $V$ together with a map $+\colon V \times V \to V$ (called "addition") and a map $\cdot\colon \mathbb{R} \times V \to V$ (called "scalar multiplication") satisfying a certain list of axioms. One of those axioms is that there is an element $0 \in V$ such that $u + 0 = 0 + u = u$ for all $u \in V$. This element is conventionally called the "zero vector" and labelled with the symbol $0$.

A key thing to note here is that this says nothing about what the elements of $V$ (either the zero vector or the other elements) *are*, just how they *act* under the given addition and scalar multiplication operations. What the elements *are* is completely irrelevant except to the extent that this is used in defining the vector space operations. In other words, the thing that "acts like a zero vector" *is* the zero vector, by definition.

In particular, there's no notion of "coordinates/entries of a vector" for elements of a general vector space. That notion arises when we choose a *basis* for a vector space; a choice of basis gives a one-to-one correspondence between elements of the vector space and lists of real numbers (indexed by the basis elements). In the finite-dimensional case, this gives the familiar representation of a vector as a finite list of real numbers. And once you choose a basis, you can indeed prove that the representation of the zero vector in any basis has all coordinates zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice vector space: The set of all functions, which takes real numbers to real numbers.

This is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$: Adding two functions together gives another function, multiplying a function with a scalar still gives a function, addition is associative, ect.

The zero vector in this example is the constant function, $z(t)=0$ for all $t$.

You can check for yourself that if you take any other function and add it to $z$, that you will get the same function back. Also, given any function $f$, you can define $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(t)=-f(t)$, and you will get that $f+g=z$.  However, the function $z$ is not "the vector with all zero elements", like you would see for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In general, vector spaces do not look like lists of elements from the base field.